# How do I upgrade boost progress?

Tags: c++, boost

Version 1.71.0 of [boost/progress.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/boost/progress.hpp) warns me:

```
include/boost/timer.hpp:21:98: note: #pragma message: This header is deprecated. 
Use the facilities in <boost/timer/timer.hpp> instead.
BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED( "the facilities in <boost/timer/timer.hpp>" )
```

But when I look in [boost/timer.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/boost/timer/timer.hpp) there's no obvious path to upgrade, since there is no `boost::progress_display` class.

In what way do the Boost folks intend for me to circumnavigate the deprecation of `progress.hpp`, other than rewriting it?

Comment: "In what way do the Boost folks intend for me to circumnavigate the deprecation of progress.hpp, other than rewriting it?" - By switching to / upgrading to, the latest version of Boost.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Obviously, as suggested by the deprecation message. However, there does not appear to be a replacement for `boost::progress_display`, so it is unclear how to upgrade.

Comment: @Richard: I don't see any instructions on how to upgrade, and hence it looks like this needs to become a github issue: https://github.com/boostorg/timer/issues

Answer (score 5):

There's not a good solution today.
Your choices are:

- use an older boost that doesn't have the deprecation warning
- ignore the warning
- write a replacement
- wait for boost 1.72 and use: `#include <boost/timer/progress_display.hpp>`

I ran into the same issue and found this summary:
https://github.com/boostorg/timer/issues/12

Comment: Thanks, @Rudy: I opened that issue :-)